# How to display all results for a given div, not just one - puppeter

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Excuse me, but the documentation is a little incomprehensible to me.

I use the argument:

```
const myDiv = await page.$$eval(".myDiv", myDiv => myDiv.textContent);
```

but the console.log will only return one result while the results for this div are >10.

How do I display them all ?

edit// That's my code that I'm learning from

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('mypage');
  // await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  
  await page.waitForSelector(".myDiv");
  
  const myDiv = await page.$eval(".myDiv", myDiv => myDiv.textContent);
  
  console.log(myDiv);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: give more information.

Comment: maybe not all divs have a textContent? Try `const myDiv = await page.$$eval(".myDiv", myDiv => myDiv);` to see if your selector matches all the divs.

Please be more specific and show more code. It is really impossible to answer for sure, with this small snipped

Comment: it returns to me [ {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},  and the same thing, but with one$ ( await page.$eval), it returns the error to me Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector ".myDiv"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [page.evaluate](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```js
const myDiv = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv'))
  return divs.map(d => d.textContent)
});
```

Function passed to `page.evaluate` will be serialized and sent to browser, so it is executed in browser context (not Node).

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide more code, this answer is pretty opinionated and maybe doesn't solve your problem. But it shows you a way how to understand what is happening.

Exspecially in developement, it's very helpful to use a combination of `page.exposeFunction()` and `page.evaluate()` to see what is going on in the browser and also in node/puppeteer.
Here is a draft which I hope it helps you to understand.

```
(async () => {
  function executedInNodeContext(result) {
    //this prints in the Node Console
    console.log(result);
  }

  function executedInBrowserContext() {
    console.log('Im in the Browser');
    const myDiv = [...document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv')];
    window.nameOfNodeFunction(myDiv);
  }

  // See the browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  // Create a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Callback in Node Context
  await page.exposeFunction('nameOfNodeFunction', executedInNodeContext);

  // Send puppeteer to a Url
  await page.goto('http://localhost/awesome/URL');

  // Function executed in the Browser on the given page
  await page.evaluate(executedInBrowserContext);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`page.$$eval()` sends in its callback an array with elements, so you need something like this to get all elements data:

```js
const myDivs = await page.$$eval(".myDiv", divs => divs.map(div => div.textContent));
```